# I'm trying to run Node.js chat application what I have downloaded from git hub. So I'm getting error like "object is not a function"

Tags: node.js, express

This is my app.js code

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io') (server);// Encountered problem in this line "(server)object is not a function"

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also run this [chat application](https://github.com/amirrajan/nodejs-chat) and its working fine.

The problem is in this line :

```
var io = require('socket.io') (server);
```

Try this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

you forget to write .listen(server)

Comment: Thanks, your answer very helpful to me. Now application worked